# How to find the angle between the line passing through two points in 3d

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

There are points $P(1,1,2), Q(3,-2,2), R(1,4,6), S(-1,10,30)$. How do I find the angle between the line passing through $P$ and $Q$, and the line passing through $R$ and $S$?

Am I supposed to find the distance between the points $P$ & $Q$ and $R$ & $S$? and then use that to find the angle?

Comment: To define an angle, you need two lines. Right now, you have one line. Where is the other?

Comment: $\langle a,  b \rangle = |a||b| \cos{\theta}$

Comment: When you say "the angle of the line", do you mean the angle between the line and a coordinate plane? For example, the angle between the line $PQ$ and the $xy$-plane, or the inclination angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(1,1,2), Q(3,-2,2), R(1,4,6), S(-1,10,30)$

equation of line $PQ$ is $(x,y,z)=(1,1,2)+t(3-1,-2-1,2-2)=(1,1,2)+t(2,-3,0)$
$$
PQ:\begin{cases}
x=1+2t\\
y=1-3t\\
z=2\\
\end{cases}\to \vec{a}=(2,-3,0)
$$
$RS$ has equation $(x,y,z)=(1,4,6)+u(-1-1,10-4,30-6)=(1,4,6)+u(-2,6,24)$
$$
RS:\begin{cases}
x=1-2u\\
y=4+6u\\
z=6+24u\\
\end{cases}\to \vec{b}=(-2,6,24)
$$

call $\alpha$ the angle between the two lines.

$\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are the direction vector of the two lines.

$$\cos\alpha=\frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|}$$
That is

$$\cos\alpha=\frac{(2,-3,0)\cdot(-2,6,24)}{||(2,-3,0)||\cdot||(-2,6,24)||}=-\sqrt{\frac{11}{182}}$$
$$\alpha\approx 104.23°$$

Comment: So you found the vector equation of the lines? Also, is "t" and "u" the vectors for the lines PQ and RS?

Comment: No, t and u are the parameters to describe the lines. I'll add something to make it clear @EmmaW

Comment: Why am I getting the angle to be $104.2^o$?

Comment: @Math777 You are right! thank you for the correction

Answer (score 0):

Relative to the origin as in vectors:$$v = \arccos\left(\frac{x_1x_2 + y_1y_2 + z_1z_2}{\sqrt{(x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2) \cdot (x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2)}}\right)$$

Comment: Since you edited your question, here is my new answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463415/angle-between-two-3d-lines

Comment: Thanks for linking. Perhaps we should also check that the two lines actually intersect? Otherwise, there’s no “angle” to speak of.

Comment: So do I check to see if the lines are parallel or not?

Comment: Yes, by subtracting the corresponding coordinates for the two points on each line to get the displacement vector then checking if one displacement vector is a multiple of the other. If they are, the lines are parallel.

Comment: @BenjaminWang If you have skew lines the formula is the same https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLZ5y6Xih-4