# How to calculate the angle ∠XAY' for this 3D geometry problem?

Tags: geometry

[image: Calculate angle XAY']

I'm running into this issue for a project:

- X, O, Y is in the horizontal 2D plane. Then length OX is known. The angle ∠XOY is known.
- Now, A is the offset of O straight up along the Z axis. The length OA = h is known. Similarly, Y' is the offset of Y straight up along the Z axis with the same length h.
- How do we calculate the angle ∠XAY' from the length OX, OA, and the angle ∠XOY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up coordinate axes in 3D space so that $O$ is placed at the origin, $A$ is placed on the positive $z$-axis at distance $h$ from the origin, $X$ lies on the positive $x$-axis at distance $d$ from the origin, and $Y$ lies in the $x-y$ plane. Assume the known angle $\angle XOY$ from $\vec{OX}$ to $\vec{OY}$ is $\theta$. We seek the angle $\alpha:=\angle XAY'$.

We can place point $Y$ at distance $r$ from the origin (the value of $r$ will cancel out). This establishes 3D coordinate vectors for all our points:

- $O=(0, 0, 0)$
- $\vec{OX}=(d, 0, 0)$
- $\vec{OA}=(0, 0, h)$
- $\vec{OY} =(r \cos \theta, r\sin \theta, 0)$
- $\vec{OY'}=(r \cos \theta, r\sin \theta, h)$.

By subtraction, determine the vectors of interest:

- $\vec{AX} = \vec{OX}-\vec{OA} = (d, 0, -h)$
- $\vec{AY'} = \vec{OY'}-\vec{OA} = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, 0)$

The angle we seek is $\alpha:=\angle XAY'$. To compute this angle we can use the [vector dot product](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463415/215011):
$$\cos \alpha = \frac {\vec{AX}\cdot\vec{AY'}}{|\vec{AX}||\vec{AY'}|}=
\frac{rd\cos\theta+0+0}{\sqrt{d^2+h^2}\,\sqrt{r^2+0^2}}=\frac{d\cos\theta}{\sqrt{d^2+h^2}}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple geometry trick that will solve this angle, so I would convert the system into vectors and [use the dot product to calculate the angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition).

Place your system in 3D space with $A$ at the origin and $X$ in the $XZ$ plane. Then
\begin{align}
A&=(0,0,0)\\
O&=(0,0,-\overline{OA})\\
X&=(\overline{OX},0,-\overline{OA})
\end{align}
Since the length $OY$ is arbitrary, assign it a length of $1$ for convenience. Then
\begin{align}
Y&=(\cos(\angle XOY),\sin(\angle XOY),-\overline{OA})\\
Y'&=(\cos(\angle XOY),\sin(\angle XOY),0)
\end{align}
The formula for $\angle XAY'$ is given by
$$\cos(\angle XAY')=\frac{\vec{AX}\cdot\vec{AY'}}{||\vec{AX}||\ ||\vec{AY'}||}\\$$
The components of that equation are
\begin{align}
\vec{AX}&=(\overline{OX},0,-\overline{OA})\\
||\vec{AX}||&=\sqrt{(\overline{OX})^2+(\overline{OA})^2}\\
\vec{AY'}&=(\cos(\angle XOY),\sin(\angle XOY),0)\\
||\vec{AY'}||&=\sqrt{\cos^2(\angle XOY)+\sin^2(\angle XOY)}=1
\end{align}
The dot product is
\begin{align}
\vec{AX}\cdot\vec{AY'}&=(\overline{OX})\cos(\angle XOY)+(0)\sin(\angle XOY)+-\overline{OA}(0)\\
&=(\overline{OX})\cos(\angle XOY)
\end{align}
Rearranging for $\angle XAY'$
$$\angle XAY'=\arccos\left(\frac{(\overline{OX})\cos(\angle XOY)}{\sqrt{(\overline{OX})^2+(\overline{OA})^2}}\right)$$
[Here is the system on Math3d](https://www.math3d.org/rndm5plJX)